# Jekyll - Pagination issues

Tags: ruby, pagination, jekyll

I am using jekyll and am trying to use pagination. From what I have read pagination can only work in html files(Like `for` lists). So when I went to impliment it I just went into my config.yml and added

```
pageinate: 5
paginate_path: "Blog/page:num"
```

and in `Blog/` I added `index.html` which is simply

```
---
layout: blogIndex
---
```

the layout `blogIndex` contains

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();" onresize="setSize();">
        {% include header.html %}
        <div id="page">
            <div id="content" class="{{ page.title }}">
            {% for post in paginator.posts %}
                <div class="post">
                    <a class="bTitle" href="{{post.url}}">{{post.title}}</a>
                    <div class="date">
                        {{post.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="pContent">
                        {{post.excerpt}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
             </div>
        </div>
        {% include footer.html %}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I generate my site and go to /Blog it does not seam to work, no posts show up when I have 12 posts created, but when I  replace `paginator` with `site` it will list all my post(So its defiantly paginator that's not working). Is there something I am doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `paginate` as `pageinate` in **config.yml**.  It should be:

```
paginate: 5
paginate_path: "Blog/page:num"
```